# Cannot setup ssh(dropbear) key login

Tags: ssh, openwrt, dropbear

Dropbear config is `/etc/config/dropbear`:

```
config dropbear
    option Port '22'
    option Interface 'lan'
    option RootPasswordAuth 'off'
    option PasswordAuth 'on'
```

I've paste my public ssh key into `/etc/dropbear/authorized_keys` and `/home/miuser/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

But when I try to connect

```
~$ ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -i ~/path/to/secret/key miuser@192.168.1.1
miuser@192.168.1.1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

However password auth to user `miuser` works. Auth to `root` user with key also works, but not to user `miuser`.

Permissions are

```
/home/miuser:
.:
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root           224 Mar 22 16:25 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root           224 Mar 22 15:05 ..
drwx--x--x    2 miuser   miuser         232 Mar 22 16:25 .ssh

/home/miuser/.ssh:
drwx--x--x    2 miuser   miuser         232 Mar 22 16:25 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root           224 Mar 22 16:25 ..
-rw-------    1 miuser   miuser        1362 Mar 22 16:37 authorized_keys

/etc/dropbear/:
drwx------    1 root     root           400 Mar 22 16:11 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          2176 Mar 22 15:16 ..
-rw-------    1 root     root           734 Mar 22 16:37 authorized_keys

/etc/config/dropbear:
-rw-------    1 root     root           117 Mar 22 16:20 /etc/config/dropbear
```

Comment: change permissions of `.ssh` directory to be 700

Comment: Which type of SSH key do you use? In the past, I had used dropbear ssh it was only possible with ssh-rsa keys, but not e.g. ssh-ed25519.

Comment: What do the logs from the dropbear ssh server show you?